# How to measure the time it takes for a request to start being serviced in node.js

Tags: node.js, server, backend

If, for example, a node server receives 1000 requests at the same time, these requests will wait in a queue of events to be processed. What I want to know is the time it takes between request arrives in the event loop until the moment the request starts processing. I need to measure this for all requests.

Answer (score 0):

This would help I guess

```
console.time('fuctionName')
    
fuctionName()
    
console.timeEnd('fuctionName')
```